# Retrieving data from Firestore stops for a longer collection with python admin SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have problems to retrieve (export) data from the Firestore database using the python SDK. Below is the code, I'm using. It connects successfully and starts retrieving the data as expected, but then after a while, it stops without any warning or error message. 
It varies as well, after how many retrieved documents it stops every time I run the script.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

account = 'path-to-keys.json'
cred = credentials.Certificate(account)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

project_ref = db.collection(u'test-collection')

db_values = project_ref.get()

values = []
for v in db_values:
    cv = v.to_dict()
    values.append(cv)

# later the values list is saved as a json
```

Do you have any hint what am I doing wrong, or how could I force the script to finish downloading all documents of the collection? The official documentation is a little sparse on the topic.

### Edit:

After playing around a little bit, if I insert a `sleep(0.05)` into the loop, the program throws this exception:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

Implementation of the same logic with NodeJS, throws this error anyway. 
A workaround there is to use pagination to iterate through the data. But somehow ordering by timestamp doesn't work from python, I always get empty array back.